# Get ApexCodeCoverageAggregate resultes in CSV

Tags: code-coverage, workbench

I am using the belwo querying in *Query Editor* in Developer Console:

```
SELECT ApexClassOrTrigger.Name, NumLinesCovered, NumLinesUncovered FROM ApexCodeCoverageAggregate
```

Enabling the Tooling API like below:

[image]

I need to the results of the query in CSV or something to analyze.

When I am running the query in Workbench, I am getting below error:

[image]

How can I enale Tooling API in Workbench?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For tooling API you should do a REST Explorer get request.

On utility tab select Rest Explorer select GET.

```
/services/data/v46.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT ApexClassOrTrigger.Name, NumLinesCovered, NumLinesUncovered FROM ApexCodeCoverageAggregate
```

You will get the resuls, But this seems not so friendly, this will not solve your Problem.

[image]

**To get the .csv of test class**

I am using  [Salesforce advanced Code searcher chrome extiontion](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-advanced-code/lnkgcmpjkkkeffambkllliefdpjdklmi) which has the very good other option too, Once add to chrome, Reload the Home Page of your org. Click to the second tab you will get the many ways to get the code coverage with download option.

[image]

Comment: Salesforce advanced Code searcher has done the thing. Great tool.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Code Coverage Report Generator](https://codecoveragereportgenerator.herokuapp.com/). This application uses tooling API to fetch code coverage details.
[image]
URL: https://codecoveragereportgenerator.herokuapp.com/